# Why string type allows to use as constant?

Tags: c#, string, constants

Why string type allows to use as constant?

Because the string gets initialise in heap so how they can use as constant. 
how does the compiler know the size of the string? and what is string table ?  is that used for calculating the string length.

if I used the string constant many places in the application, does it increase the memory consumption?

Comment: Constants in C# simply compile verbatim. So, when you have `const string something = "testing";` and then you write `Console.WriteLine(something)`, the compiler replaces it with `Console.WriteLine("testing")`. Strings are interned in C#, so no, duplicate constant strings will not take more memory. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636363/string-caching-memory-optimization-and-re-use

Comment: Thanks, @Rob, but why  they allow to use as constant because no reference types have used as constant.

Comment: They're immutable.  And constants can be numbers, boolean values, strings, or a null reference.

Comment: @AnkitRana Strings are a special type of reference type, in that they can be constructed at compile time, unlike other reference types. Hence, they can be marked `constant`.

Comment: then why dateTime is not allowed to declare as constant ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .NET team could have gone ahead and allowed arbitrary expressions to be used as constants — e.g. `new Vector2(0, 0)` if the `Vector2` constructor was known to have no external side effects and the type was known to be a struct or otherwise immutable. But they simply didn't take the time to do this, perhaps because figuring out these requirements is extra work for the compilers (remember, C# has no `immutable` or `pure` keywords yet).

The `string` type is special to the compiler and the runtime: it was designed from the start to be immutable and its constructors have no externally observable side-effects, so the creators of the .NET runtime baked this knowledge into the compiler. That's why `string` has literals and gets special treatment.

Still, they probably wanted to avoid teaching the infrastructure too many special types — just a handful of fundamental types, namely primitives and strings. `DateTime` simply wasn't deemed important enough to be included.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, does use float as constant increase memory consumption ?

Comment: @AnkitRana Is there any reason why you are asking about `float` specifically? The same should hold for all kinds of constants.

Comment: please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819117/c-sharp-do-const-fields-use-less-memory

Answer (score 3):

> Constants can be numbers, Boolean values, strings, or a null reference.
>
> A constant expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile time. Therefore, the only possible values for constants of reference types are string and a null reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const

Strings can be fully evaluated at compile time.  `DateTime`s cannot.

Comment: so how they find the string length in compile time?

Comment: It's a string literal.  The compiler is able to count the characters.  It's the same way the string length is calculated at runtime.  But this doesn't have anything to do with your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Because a const string is not treated as a reference, it becomes a literal.